# Вызов метода при динамическом связывании

Tags: java

```
class A
{
    public void show()
    {
        print("A");
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public void show()
    {
        print("B");
    }
}

class C
{
    main()
    {
        A a = new B();
        a.show(); // вызывается метод show из класса B, но нужен из класса A
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class C
{
      main()
      {
            A a = new A();
            a.show(); // вызывается метод show из класса B, но нужен из клсса A
      }
}
```

фокус-покус. вызывается то что тебе нужно. Ещё варианты:

- используй слово super в классе B
- используй статический метод в классе А. статик методы не переопределяются

Comment: совсем не то что нужно, нужно что бы вызывался именно метод класса  A, при A a = new B(); например если я определю еще один метод только в классе A например show2(), то я могу его вызвать так A a = new B();  a.show2(); почему так нельзя сделать при одинаковых именах?

Comment: @user176569 потому что по умолчанию ищется верхний в иерархии метод.

Comment: @user176569 это в С++ можно было так сделать. Но! С точки зрения понятности это очень плохой подход. Я спрошу по другому. Зачем вам это?

Comment: В прицепе особо мне это ПОКА не нужно я просто изучаю java. В C++ знаю как это делается A *a = new B(); a->A::show();(для виртуальных методов) . Чиста из за интереса решил узнать как подобное можно сделать в java.